# How can I override Github Actions or Cloud Build `skip ci`?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

So i have a catch 22 with CI currently.
I need to `[skip ci]` on cloud build on a certain merge to main because that build will eventually be triggered by tags created by a github action. However, github actions also listens to `[skip ci]` and doesn't run... I can't figure out how to override the skip syntax on either, but perhaps I'm also asking the wrong question. Help?

There are work arounds to `exit 0` in cloud build steps, but I'd have to override that in every step that is triggered, so not ideal. I'd like the github action to always trigger, so it would be nice to disable any skip ci logic on that workflow.

CI triggers:

- Merge to main: Cloud build to build app
- Merge to main: Check for changesets.

  - Logic to either open/rebase version update PR, or
  - **Create tags**
- New tag: run cloud build

Desired flow:

- If I merge my version update PR, I don't want cloud build to run.
- Instead, I want my github action to run and create tags.
- Then, once the tags are created, use that trigger to do my cloud build.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a relevant workflow file for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Oh my bad, edited for clarity

Comment: Would setting cloud build to listen to tags instead of commits work for you? Or do you need have cloud build ignore certain commits and build on others?

Comment: The tags trigger unfortunately respects the `[skip ci]`.

I ended up writing a pile of skip logic in cloudbuild 